# Are multiple onsubmit javascript functions allowed in a forms?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, onsubmit

Are multiple onsubmit functions allowed in forms?
Example:

```
<form name="form" method="POST" action="contactus.asp" onsubmit="return verify()" 
<!--*****CAN I ADD ANOTHER onsubmit FUNCTION HERE?***** -->>
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can add any legal JavaScript statement including this:

```
<form onsubmit="return verify1() && verify2()">
```

or this

```
<form onsubmit="return verify1() || verify2()">
```

or more complex expressions which can include multiple function calls. Note that standard evaluation rules apply including short-circuit evaluation of logical expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that wouldn't work.  You should just make a wrapper function, and include the functions which you desire to execute, inside of that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var run1 = function() { alert("first"); }
    var run2 = function() { alert("second"); }

    function sub() {
        run1();
        run2();
    }
</script>
<form name="form" method="POST" action="contactus.asp" onsubmit="javascript:sub();">
```